# MSDN activations

Tags: license, msdn, software-activation

MSDN activations have a soft limit of 10 per product, correct?  If I log in to MSDN, does it display a count of current activations per product?

Comment: I don't see why this would belong on StackOverflow, it's about using MSDN, not MSDN library.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it should. It would make things a lot easier than trying to remember yourself. Nothing's worse than doing a full reinstall of something just to find out your key is no longer valid.

Comment: You can just get a new key from the subscriptions website though. We blew our key for XP due to many installs in VMs over time for testing, and got a new key without any hassle. No doubt there is a trigger somewhere that will go off if you do this too much, but as those 10 licenses are intended for testing purposes this sort of occurance must be expected to not be rare.